# can't start scala on windows 7

Tags: scala

I downloaded scala 2.8 but when executing scala.bat it says

system cannot find set_home

I didn't have this problem with old version of scala.

So how to launch scala ?

Update: I'm on windows 7, I have setup JAVA_HOME environment variable. the problem is the set_home batch command that is not known.

I have found the official tutorial here:
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/310

I did exactly like they asked but
IT DOESN'T WORK WITH SCALA 2.8 ON WINDOWS 7

It seems they didn't test !

This is their batch file (scala.bat), I don't see when scala is even started!:

```
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" (
  @setlocal
  call :set_home
  set _ARGS=%*
) else (
  set _SCALA_HOME=%SCALA_HOME%
  rem The following line tests SCALA_HOME instead of _SCALA_HOME, because
  rem the above change to _SCALA_HOME is not visible within this block.
  if "%SCALA_HOME%"=="" goto error1
  call :set_args
)

rem We use the value of the JAVACMD environment variable if defined
set _JAVACMD=%JAVACMD%

if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" (
  if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
  )
)

if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=java

rem We use the value of the JAVA_OPTS environment variable if defined
set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
if "%_JAVA_OPTS%"=="" set _JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256M -Xms32M

set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=
if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
  for %%f in ("%_SCALA_HOME%\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
  if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" (
    for /d %%f in ("%_SCALA_HOME%\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
  )
)
```

Comment: I have Windows Vista, scala-2.8.0.final. I have java 1.6 in my path and I can run scala.bat. What version of Windows do you have? And by old version of Scala, you mean 2.7.x?

Comment: I have updated my post: I'm on Windows 7. I don't remember the old version because I did it one year ago I think it was an exe not a batch file that's why it did work well.

Comment: Don't assume that because it doesn't work for you, it doesn't work for everybody (which you seem to be doing when you say "It seems they didn't test !"). It works fine on my Windows 7 system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did test it on Windows 7, and just to be sure I tested it again now and it works for me (Windows 7, 64 bit).

Can you please show the output of running the following commands:

```
C:\Users\luc\Desktop\scala-2.8.0.final>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\

C:\Users\luc\Desktop\scala-2.8.0.final>java -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

C:\Users\luc\Desktop\scala-2.8.0.final>bin\scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.
6.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 1+1
res0: Int = 2
```

Did you post the full batch script? If so, it's corrupted, it should contain more code below (and comments above). Try downloading again.

```
@echo off

rem ##########################################################################
rem # Copyright 2002-2010, LAMP/EPFL
rem #
rem # This is free software; see the distribution for copying conditions.
rem # There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
rem # PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
rem ##########################################################################

rem We adopt the following conventions:
rem - System/user environment variables start with a letter
rem - Local batch variables start with an underscore ('_')

if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" (
  @setlocal
  call :set_home
  set _ARGS=%*
) else (
  set _SCALA_HOME=%SCALA_HOME%
  rem The following line tests SCALA_HOME instead of _SCALA_HOME, because
  rem the above change to _SCALA_HOME is not visible within this block.
  if "%SCALA_HOME%"=="" goto error1
  call :set_args
)

rem We use the value of the JAVACMD environment variable if defined
set _JAVACMD=%JAVACMD%

if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" (
  if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
  )
)

if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=java

rem We use the value of the JAVA_OPTS environment variable if defined
set _JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
if "%_JAVA_OPTS%"=="" set _JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256M -Xms32M

set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=
if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
  for %%f in ("%_SCALA_HOME%\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
  if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" (
    for /d %%f in ("%_SCALA_HOME%\lib\*") do call :add_cpath "%%f"
  )
)

set _PROPS=-Dscala.home="%_SCALA_HOME%" -Denv.emacs="%EMACS%" 

rem echo "%_JAVACMD%" %_JAVA_OPTS% %_PROPS% -cp "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%" scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  %_ARGS%
"%_JAVACMD%" %_JAVA_OPTS% %_PROPS% -cp "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%" scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  %_ARGS%
goto end

rem ##########################################################################
rem # subroutines

:add_cpath
  if "%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
    set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=%~1
  ) else (
    set _TOOL_CLASSPATH=%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%;%~1
  )
goto :eof

rem Variable "%~dps0" works on WinXP SP2 or newer
rem (see http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=833431)
rem set _SCALA_HOME=%~dps0..
:set_home
  set _BIN_DIR=
  for %%i in (%~sf0) do set _BIN_DIR=%_BIN_DIR%%%~dpsi
  set _SCALA_HOME=%_BIN_DIR%..
goto :eof

:set_args
  set _ARGS=
  :loop
  rem Argument %1 may contain quotes so we use parentheses here
  if (%1)==() goto :eof
  set _ARGS=%_ARGS% %1
  shift
  goto loop

rem ##########################################################################
rem # errors

:error1
echo ERROR: environment variable SCALA_HOME is undefined. It should point to your installation directory.
goto end

:end
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" @endlocal
```

Comment: Yes it's the full batch I copied so yes I will download again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `bin` directory of your Scala installation to your `PATH` environment variable.

For example, if you installed Scala in `C:\Dev\scala-2.8.0.final`, then add `C:\Dev\scala-2.8.0.final\bin` to your `PATH`.

Look here for instructions on how to change `PATH` on Windows 7:

[How to Add, Remove or Edit Environment variables in Windows 7?](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html)

Note: You have to close and re-open the command prompt after you set an environment variable; if you leave the command prompt open, it will not pick up the change.

Comment: I've done it of course. I'm not beginner, I know DOS since its existance :).

Comment: hey, but can you tell how to find bin if I installed just plug in for scala in my eclipse IDE ?

Comment: @kolboc I don't know, I don't use Eclipse with Scala. Download Scala from http://www.scala-lang.org/